# Is every holomorphic function in a neighborhood of the origin of $C^n$ necessarily bounded?

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Is every holomorphic function in a neighborhood of the origin of $C^n$ necessarily bounded?

In which case the statement can be true?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't the identity function a counterexample to this?

Comment: There are some contexts in which "any" is an ambiguous word.  "Is any holomorphic function in a neighborhood of the origin of $\mathbb C^n$ necessarily bounded?".  That could mean "Is there any holomorphic function in a neighborhood of the origin of $\mathbb C^n$ that is necessarily bounded?" or it could mean "Is every holomorphic function in a neighborhood of the origin of $\mathbb C^n$ necessarily bounded?".  If the latter was intended, then merely changing "any" to "every" would disambiguate it.

Comment: The idntity function is bounded iff the neighborhood is bounded

Comment: Is this your question: Let $U$ be a neighborhood of the origin in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Under what conditions on $U$ is every holomorphic function on $U$ bounded?

Comment: Or is this your question: if $f$ is a holomorphic function on a neighbourhood $U$ of the origin, then does there exist an open subset $V\subseteq U$ such that $f$ is bounded on $V$?

Comment: (The answers to both of the questions I mentioned above are straightforward; if you can state in which question you're interested, then I can elaborate.)

Comment: @Amitesh Datta I meant the first. But could you elaborate the answer to both of the statements

Comment: I have no idea why you accepted a wrong (or at least very incomplete) answer.

Comment: Well, I agree with @mrf even though I was the author of the answer in question. The answer he provided is definitely much better (and he obviously knows much more about several complex variables than I do!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the request of the OP and the clarification of the original question (see the comment thread above), here's my answer:

**Question**: Let $U$ be a neighborhood of the the origin in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Under what conditions on $U$ is every holomorphic function on $U$ bounded?

**Answer**: No such conditions exist. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of the origin in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and let's assume $U\neq \mathbb{C}^n$ (if $U=\mathbb{C}^n$, then take identity function). The boundary of $U$ is $\text{Bd}(U)=\overline{U}\setminus U$ and is non-empty. Let $a\in \text{Bd}(U)$ and choose the function $\frac{1}{z-a}$. It is holomorphic on $U$ but unbounded.

**Question**: If $f$ is a holomorphic function on a neighborhood $U$ of the origin, then does there exist an open subset $V\subseteq U$ such that $f$ is bounded on $V$?

**Answer**: Yes, always. Chose a neighborhood $V$ of the origin with compact closure such that $\overline{V}\subseteq U$. Holomorphic functions are continuous and continuous functions on compact sets are bounded. So, the restriction of any holomorphic function on $U$ to $V$ is bounded.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This answer is essentially correct, but there are some notational issues centering around $\mathbb{C}$ versus $\mathbb{C}^n$.  For instance, if $n > 1$, then "the identity map" is not a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}^n$, since holomorphic functions map into $\mathbb{C}$.  Similarly $\frac{1}{z-a}$ doesn't make sense, since we can't take the multiplicative inverse of a vector.  But this is all easily fixed...

Comment: I noticed the same thing as @Pete, but got stuck on the easy fix. How do we know that some $\dfrac1{z_j-a_j}$ is holo on $U$?

Comment: @Ted: I agree with you: the fix is not as easy as I had implied.  In fact, I will go to sleep now rather than trying to fix it...

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no. If the neighbourhood $U$ is unbounded, at least one of the coordinate functions is a counterexample.

If the neighbourhood is bounded, let $p\in\partial U$ be a point of maximal distance $r$ from the origin. Let $l(z) = a_1z_1 + \cdots + a_nz_n + b$ be an affine function such that $l(p)=0$, but $l(z)\neq 0$ on $U$. (Choose the coefficients so that the zero set of $l$ is contained in the tangent space of $B_r(0)$.) Finally, let $$f(z) = \frac1{l(z)}.$$

This construction shows that at least one point of $\partial U$ is pseudoconvex.

Comment: +1 Great answer! This solution definitely identifies the main difficulty (which my solution didn't).